# magit fails to install

Tags: package, magit

I am unable to install **magit** with **package.el**. While other packages install correctly, **magit** (v 90150116) currently gives me:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (wrong-number-of-arguments
#[(ad--addoit-function package-list requirements) "\304\305 !\306   !\210

    \304#\211)\207" [ad-return-value requirements ad--addoit-function
package-list nil reverse print] 5] 4)  
ad-Advice-package-compute-transaction(#[770
"\211\203I\211@\211@\211A@\262\302\211\2038esc magit (90150116)
"control Git from Emacs" ((cl-lib (0 3)) (git-commit-mode (0 14 0))
(git-rebase-mode (0 14 0))) tar "melpa-stable" nil ((:keywords "vc"
"tools")) nil]))   apply(ad-Advice-package-compute-transaction #[770
"\211\203I\211@\211@\211A@\262\302\211\20383)) (git-commit-mode
(0 14 0)) (git-rebase-mode (0 14 0))) tar "melpa-stable" nil
((:keywords "vc" "tools")) nil])))  
package-compute-transaction(([cl-struct-package-desc magit (90150116)
"control Git from Emacs" ((cl-lib (0 3)) (git-commit-mode (0 14 0))
(git-rebase-mode (0 14 0))) tar "melpa-stable" nil ((:keywords "vc"
"tools")) nil]) ((cl-lib (0 3)) (git-commit-mode (0 14 0))
(git-rebase-mode (0 14 0))) ([cl-struct-package-desc magit (90150116)
"control Git from Emacs" ((cl-lib (0 3)) (git-commit-mode (0 14 0))
(git-rebase-mode (0 14 0))) tar "melpa-stable" nil ((:keywords "vc"
"tools")) nil]))   #[770
"\211\203I\211@\211@\211A@\262\302\211\2038/24.4/lisp/emacs-lisp/package.elc"
. 39624)](nil ((magit)) nil)  
ad-Advice-package-compute-transaction(#[770
"\211\203I\211@\211@\211A@\262\302\211\20384\211A\262\242\211\303H>\204\272
```

I'm using http://stable.melpa.org and **emacs 24.4.1**, compiled locally.

Comment: I would submit an issue to the package maintainer on Github -- include your Emacs version and OS, and before the maintainer asks, try installing it with a virtually blank/empty `.emacs` file to verify you have nothing in your setup that is conflicting with the installation -- you should also make sure you are trying the install with the latest public release of Emacs.  In the meantime, you can get everything directly from Github without using `package.el`.  I can verify it was possible to set up Magit by hand on my own computer -- i.e., installing all of the dependencies without `package.el`.

Comment: @lawlist in this case I think @dmvianna is better served by asking here, as I don't think it's a magit issue. The backtrace indicates the error occurs somewhere in `package.el`, or rather that there is an error in an advice which was added to `package-list`. I don't know much about `package.el` so all I can suggest is trying to figure out what is advising that function.

Comment: Just in case: have you restarted emacs? And hhave you tried installing other packages? package.el sometimes becomes unusable for me, erroring on every install. I just restart emacs when this happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was the latest stable **magit** wasn't compatible with the version of **git** I had in my system. As stated in [another question I posted](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/9939/magit-fails-to-create-local-repository), magit works fine with latest stable git (in my case, 2.3.x).