# Magit fails to create local repository

Tags: magit

This is what I got when I select a directory (whether it had a git repository) and choose "yes" when magit asks if I want to create one:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (wrong-type-argument stringp nil)
directory-file-name(nil)
magit-mode-get-buffer("*magit: %t*" magit-status-mode)
magit-refresh()
magit-run-git("init" "/home/user/local/dir/")
magit-init("~/local/dir/")
magit-status("~/local/dir/")
call-interactively(magit-status record nil)
command-execute(magit-status record)
execute-extended-command(nil "magit-status")
call-interactively(execute-extended-command nil nil)
command-execute(execute-extended-command)
```

I'm using:

- **magit** (v 90150116), from http://stable.melpa.org
- **emacs 24.4.1**, compiled locally.

Verified with a bare `init.el`.

Comment: There's something hazy with your description: why would magit ask to create a new repository in a directory with an existing repository? - That shouldn't happen. From the stack trace it looks like magit failed to create status buffer / failed to find what directory is being worked with, but maybe that's because `git init` has failed (on an existing repository)? Could it be a permission issue? Maybe your user can't access this directory?

Comment: I could not reproduce this, when there is a repository then magit shows its status, when there is none and I answer that it should create one, then it does so and then shows its status. By guess is that your version of git is to old or that there are symlinks involved.

Comment: @tarsius, I'm using git 1.7.1, and I don't have superuser access. Are any easy workarounds possible (like getting an old version of magit) or am I forced to compile git from source? What is the earliest compatible git release?

Comment: You'll have to compile it from source then. If I remember correctly `make install` by default installs in you home directory. For the master branch you need 1.8.2 and for the next 1.9.1. But you might just as well install the latest version.

Comment: @tarsius you were right. **magit** works fine with latest stable git (2.3.x).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@tarsius was right. **magit** works fine with latest stable git (2.3.x).